# 2 way 0.1" jumper sockets - which way up?

Tags: connector

Simple question. This is a typical 2 way jumper socket:

[image]

Which way is up? [I suspect in practice it doesn't matter, but still curious]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the data sheet:
[image]

The end opposite where the pins go is the "Top".

Comment: But is the data sheet describing two (or four) different sockets?

Answer (score 1):

If the order of your jumper is M7567-05 and according to the datasheet   [image]  your jumper is open top high rel, see the direction of pin insertion for the open top in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

- The end visible in your picture has beveled holes clearly intended to align pins inserted in that end. So that end is the bottom.
- In most jumpers I have seen, there is one end where you can see the metal actually bridging the two sides, and that end is the top.
- If there is a groove near one end, it is for grasping the jumper and that end is the top.